# Twilio Outbound text/sms number format to Verizon/AT&T iPhones in USA

Tags: iphone, twilio

I am using Twilio to send an outbound SMS/Text to two different cells phones on two different carriers.

For example:

- Twilio Number is (800) 555-5555
- Verizon Number is (949) 444-4444
- AT&T Number is (949) 777-7777

When I send an SMS/Text from Twilio (800-555-5555) to Verizon (949-444-4444) the number on the Verzion phone appears as 800-555-5555

When I send an SMS/Text from Twilio (800-555-5555) to AT&T (949-444-4444) the number on the AT&T phone appears as 1-800-555-5555

I contacted Twilio support and they say the they are sending to both Verizon and AT&T with this format: +18005555555 and it is Verizon or AT&T that is formatting the numbers on the phone.

This isn't a big issue, however, on the iPhone it does not group text messages if the numbers don't match exactly.

So if a Verizon user sends a text to 1-800-555-5555 and the outbound text from my program to the Verizon user via Twilio comes across as 800-555-5555 it is not grouped on the Verizon iPhone.

And if a AT&T user sends a text to 800-555-5555 and the outbound text from my program to the AT&T user via Twilio comes across as 1-800-555-5555 it is not grouped on the AT&T iPhone.

Ultimately, if Apple grouped the messages this wouldn't be an issue.

Anyone else seen this? Any workarounds to get either the iPhone to group the messages?